# Uploade image to FTP via php code error

Tags: php, ftp

I have problem with my image uploade, it doesnt work...
give me this error

> Connected to ftp.exemple.com, for user exemple@exemple.com Warning:
>   ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   /home/user/public_html/foto-test.php on line 26 FTP upload has
>   failed!

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "ftp.xxxx.com";
$ftp_user_name = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxxxxx";
$folder = "/public_html/images";
$destination_file = $folder . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$source_file = $_FILE['file']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); //line 26

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

I tried to change the $folder destination but it give me the some error...

Comment: I figured up, the line 26 with  `$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_ASCII);` //line 26
the problem was FTP_BINARY, so i puted FTP_ASCII

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answers here [PHP FTP upload error: Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Filename cannot be empty in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840636/php-ftp-upload-error-warning-ftp-put-function-ftp-put-filename-cannot-be)

Also your destination path should have a slash at the end

```
$folder = "/public_html/images"; 
$destination_file = $folder . $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

change that to

`$folder = "/public_html/images/"; 
$destination_file = $folder . $_FILES['file']['name'];`

So it will be clear that whatever(image) you uploading is going into the image folder and not  'image+SomeName' folder

Comment: Have you checked the link I specified?

Comment: I checked but i didnot figure up... can you be more specifically and tried to explain on this code...?

Comment: before then try uploading a file with a very small size

Comment: If it did not go you can use this to check for the specific error that happened http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118612/discussion-between-f-e-noel-nfebe-and-stefan-j).

Comment: it's give me UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. , i spoke with the guys who hosting my site, to change the uploade_max_filesize from php.ini and they did, but is give me the some, error adn the max size is 100 mb... and my image has 30kb

Comment: They might be a problem with their configurations, explain you problem to them giving details about your code they will best help you... You will get over it cheers! :)

Comment: they changed me at 100mb the limit and doesnt work... maybe is in my code something i missed, they tried uploade image using cPanel and its worked, so where can be the bug?